# How should I be handling query routes with react router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am trying to figure out how I should be handling queries with react router. The way that I am currently doing it, nothing shows up in `this.props.location.search`

Note: I am using withRouter

I am parsing the query input using the qs library

`const queryString = (q) => qs.stringify(q, { format: 'RFC1738' })`

Then, if there is a query (filter, or page change), I redirect to the required route.

```
if (toResults) {
  return (
  <Redirect
    push
    to={{pathname: `/search/${route}`}}
  />
  )
}
```

Console log inside componentDidUpdate: `{pathname: "/search/?query=some+query&page=0", search: "", hash: "", key: "5tqm1t"}`

Why isn't the query showing up in search? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Nothing wrong to see here. Please post a minimal workable example on codesandbox.io so people can help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Can you change your `to` like this way

to={{pathname: '/search', search: `/${route}` }}

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion tareq!  While this doesn't work with how my routes are set up, I was able to do it like this: `<Redirect push to={`/search/${route}`} />`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing the Redirect component's to parameter an object, I passed it as a string.  For some reason, when I passed it as an object, it caused a conflict with another route that I have set up.

```
    if (toResults) {
        return <Redirect push to={`/search/${route}`} />
    }
```

So, I modified how I was generating the URL to as follows:

```
const queryString = (q) => `q?${qs.stringify(q, { format: 'RFC1738' })}`
```